# JS Library performace exporting and importing

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ecmascript-6

My question revolves around javascript/typescript libraries and performance related to library size and size of exports/imports.

I have created a rather large Angular application that uses an Nx monorepo. I dedicate a full library to house some models. Some of these models are nested. I have some factory classes to new-up some objects with default values.

I only want to export some of the models (the top level) and some of the factories (also top level) from my library. Does limiting the number of exports improve the performance of importing? Say I have 100 interfaces and I only export 5 of these, would this be better than exporting the entire 100? What if the 5 interfaces that I export reference 50 other interfaces that aren't exported?

Also, does the size of the library impact import performance if only a small number of items are exported? Say the library has some code that processes a complex object and then just returns a result. From my understanding a larger bundle size will impact page loading and slow down the page, but I would like to optimize how my code runs.

Comment: ummmmmm. first of all im asssuming your talking about running in development mode because typescript does not work in browsers nor does some of the loading issues you have in development mode.

Comment: if you are using interfaces only the size is 0, just go to typescript playground and see the generated js. Classes however is created.